# converting json to string in php

Tags: php, json

i want to convert this json to string in php, i want it to return just the titles and descriptions.

my json output codes from my url:

```
 {"play-list":[{"id":"48","title":"Sound Remedy \u0026 Illenium - Spirals (feat. King Deco)","description":"","uid":"9","first_name":"kings ","last_name":"men","name":"Sound Remedy \u0026 Illenium - Spirals (feat. King Deco).mp3_calitone.com.mp3","tag":"jazz,","art":"1644246783images (15).jpg_www.calitone.com.jpg","buy":"","record":"","release":"0000-00-00","license":"0","size":"5800450","download":"1","time":"2017-07-14 08:15:22","public":"1","likes":"0","downloads":"0","views":"215"},{"id":"385","title":"Natalie Imbruglia - Perfectly","description":"","uid":"9","first_name":"kings ","last_name":"men","name":"Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Perfectly_calitone.com.mp3","tag":"Pop","art":"Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Perfectly_calitone.com.jpg","buy":"","record":"","release":"0000-00-00","license":"0","size":"0","download":"1","time":"2017-07-10 20:09:08","public":"1","likes":"0","downloads":"0","views":"177"},{"id":"384","title":"Natalie Imbruglia - Shiver","description":"","uid":"9","first_name":"kings ","last_name":"men","name":"Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Shiver_calitone.com.mp3","tag":"blues","art":"Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Shiver_calitone.com.jpg","buy":"","record":"","release":"0000-00-00","license":"0","size":"0","download":"1","time":"2017-07-10 20:04:08","public":"1","likes":"0","downloads":"0","views":"144"},{"id":"383","title":"Natalie Imbruglia - Torn","description":"","uid":"9","first_name":"kings ","last_name":"men","name":"Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Torn_calitone.com.mp3","tag":"blues","art":"Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Torn_calitone.com.jpg","buy":"","record":"","release":"0000-00-00","license":"0","size":"0","download":"1","time":"2017-07-10 19:58:38","public":"1","likes":"2","downloads":"2","views":"213"}],"success":1}
```

this is my function below:

```
function ct_playlist_data($id) {

    $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.calitunes.com/android_543ASBD/playlist.php?playlists=yes&listid=6'));
            $tracks = $jsonData->{'play-list'};
            //$success = $value->{'success'};
            echo var_dump($tracks);

}
```

am stuck here.

thank you in advance!

Comment: did you try the `JSON.stringify()` function? just like [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)?

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: Check the answer, might be helpful.

Comment: @eBourgess - emmm, `JSON.stringify()` is javascript, OP is asking about PHP...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example based on your JSON

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($array['play-list'] as $val) {
  echo $val['title'] . $val['description'] . '<br>';
}
```

> [SEE DEMO HERE](https://3v4l.org/OBEPf)

Comment: you code gave me this error      Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\playlist\inc\calitunes_data.php:29 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\playlist\index.php(90): playlist->ct_playlist_data('6') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\playlist\inc\calitunes_data.php on line 29

Answer (score 0):

Try this code [Demo is here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/66217fb2c03fefb6f570987698b4ba2e3675d063)

```
<?php 

$jsonData = '{"play-list":[{"id":"48","title":"Sound Remedy \u0026 Illenium - Spirals (feat. King Deco)","description":"","uid":"9","first_name":"kings ","last_name":"men","name":"Sound Remedy \u0026 Illenium - Spirals (feat. King Deco).mp3_calitone.com.mp3","tag":"jazz,","art":"1644246783images (15).jpg_www.calitone.com.jpg","buy":"","record":"","release":"0000-00-00","license":"0","size":"5800450","download":"1","time":"2017-07-14 08:15:22","public":"1","likes":"0","downloads":"0","views":"215"},{"id":"385","title":"Natalie Imbruglia - Perfectly","description":"","uid":"9","first_name":"kings ","last_name":"men","name":"Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Perfectly_calitone.com.mp3","tag":"Pop","art":"Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Perfectly_calitone.com.jpg","buy":"","record":"","release":"0000-00-00","license":"0","size":"0","download":"1","time":"2017-07-10 20:09:08","public":"1","likes":"0","downloads":"0","views":"177"},{"id":"384","title":"Natalie Imbruglia - Shiver","description":"","uid":"9","first_name":"kings ","last_name":"men","name":"Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Shiver_calitone.com.mp3","tag":"blues","art":"Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Shiver_calitone.com.jpg","buy":"","record":"","release":"0000-00-00","license":"0","size":"0","download":"1","time":"2017-07-10 20:04:08","public":"1","likes":"0","downloads":"0","views":"144"},{"id":"383","title":"Natalie Imbruglia - Torn","description":"","uid":"9","first_name":"kings ","last_name":"men","name":"Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Torn_calitone.com.mp3","tag":"blues","art":"Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Natalie_Imbruglia_-_Torn_calitone.com.jpg","buy":"","record":"","release":"0000-00-00","license":"0","size":"0","download":"1","time":"2017-07-10 19:58:38","public":"1","likes":"2","downloads":"2","views":"213"}],"success":1}';
$decode = json_decode($jsonData,true);

foreach($decode['play-list'] as $d){
  echo $d['title'];
  echo $d['description'];
}

?>
```

Comment: i need all the titles in the json

Comment: OK, simply do that using foreach. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// $json = your json    
$json = json_decode($json,true);    
$title =[];
foreach($json['play-list'] as $value) {    
    array_push($title,$value['title']);    
}

echo implode('',$title);

echo json_encode($title);
```

Can work?

Comment: add a true parameter to json_decode($json,true) can make json be a array struct.@cale_b